# Extracting substring from string between 2 strings in regex

Tags: regex

```
1)Name :        Alibaba        
Id :            1341343144           
Nationality :   ALIEN CITIZEN   
Address :       

Address Source : Address Change Date :

Position SECRETARY

1)Name :        TAN GENGQI       
Id :            14019849314        
Category :      Individual       
Nationality :   SFAEFFE CITIZEN
Address :
```

Above is the data that i have. I'm trying to extract the ID number using regex but as the "table" is alittle inconsistent, i'm unable to extract the right result. Anyone can advise me what is missing?

Below is my current code

```
 (?<=Id :)(?s)(.*?)(?=:)
```

Comment: I highly recommend e.g. https://regex101.com/ for all your regular expression experimentation. But first make sure you really *need* a regex, more often than not string extraction problems could be solved easier and simpler without regular expressions. And regular expressions tend to add a couple of layers of complexity and make code less maintainable.

Comment: Wha about: `(?<ID>\d{10,11})`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. i can just replace my (?=:) with (?=\n)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capturing group

```
\bId :\s*(\d+)\b
```

- `\bId :` A word boundary, match `Id :`
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9u57cc/1)